How to modify the CMakeLists.txt file to point to locally-installed packages
I have a package foo installed on my Fedora system, but I want to build (from source) and install a newer version of foo in my local directory.  The package has executables, static and dynamic libraries, and header files,
The 'current' package foo is under /usr/bin, /usr/lib, and /usr/include.
The newer package foo is under /home/me/.local/foo/build/bin, /home/me/.local/foo/build/lib and /home/me/.local/foo/src/include.
How do I tell my local cmake file (CMakeLists.txt) to ignore the 'current' package foo, and to use the local package foo in my local directory when building my project (which needs the libraries and headers of the local package foo).
For example, for some packages (like mysql), I use:
find_library(SQL_LIB mysql)

while for other packages (like openssl), cmake just picks the right path:
set(OSSL_LIB ssl crypto)

target_link_libraries(myapp ${SQL_LIB} ${OSSL_LIB})

Assuming that MySQL is already installed on my system, and I want to build another MySQL from source and install it under /home/me/.local/mysql, how would I tell cmake to pick up the header files and libraries under /home/me/.local/mysql (i.e.  /home/me/.local/mysql/include and /home/me/.local/mysql/lib)
I've been doing some googling and I found cmake commands like:

CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX
CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH
CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH

but I don't know which ones are the right ones to use.  The cmake documentation is vague.

It depends on the way how the other project looks for your package. Normally, adding installation prefix of your new package installation to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH variable makes the new installation to be preferable over the old one.

Thanks for your comment.  I've updated the original post to give you more information.  Your help is appreciated.
